# How can I view whether a Slack channel is only accessible by the members of a specific workspace or all the organization?

Tags: slack

How can I view whether a public Slack channel is accessible (i.e., can be joined by) by the members of only the current workspace, just a few workspaces or all the workspaces of the organization in Slack Enterprise Grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [image] symbol next to the channel name on the left panel indicates that the channel is a ["multi-workspace channel"](https://slack.com/intl/en-in/help/articles/115001399587-Create-multi-workspace-channels-on-Enterprise-Grid):

[image]

Go to the channel's details panel on the right to see which workspaces have access to the channel:

[image]

Example where the entire organization (i.e., all workspaces) has access to the channel:

[image]